# pick multiple properties using underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

```
var arr = [{Analytics:26}, {Technology:22}, {Medical:40}, {Operations:90}]
```

Output must be in the order. Starting with Operations, Medical, Analytics & Technology.

Output:

```
[90,40,26,22]
```

Comment: What governs the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the objects with

```
var merged = Object.assign({}, ...arr);
```

Then pick out the ones you want:

```
var output = [merged.Operations, merged.Medical, merged.Analytics, merged.Technology];
```

If you prefer pure Underscore:

```
var merged = _.extend({}, ...arr);
_.map(['Operations', 'Medical', 'Analytics', 'Technology'], prop => merged[prop]);
```